# Filtering dataframe with Multiindex in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

First dataframe d1: Index columns are State and City

```
                      **2008q2         2009q2          Price Ratio**
**State   City**
Alabama   Montevallo  119000.000000  125200.000000     0.950479
          Tuscaloosa  139366.666667  136933.333333     1.017770
Alaska    Fairbanks   254733.333333  225833.333333     1.127970
```

Second dataframe d2 :

```
    State    City
0  Alabama    Auburn
1  Alabama    Florence
2  Alabama    Tuscaloosa
```

I need to filter out/remove rows in d1 where [State,City] is not in d2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with `inner` join:

```
df = df2.join(df1, on=['State','City'], how='inner')
print (df)
     State        City         2008q2         2009q2  Price Ratio
2  Alabama  Tuscaloosa  139366.666667  136933.333333      1.01777
```

Another solution with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), parameter `on` can be omit if only intersection of same columns in both `df`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2)
#df = pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2, on=['State','City'])
print (df)
     State        City         2008q2         2009q2  Price Ratio
0  Alabama  Tuscaloosa  139366.666667  136933.333333      1.01777
```

Comment: inner join gives the entry common to both. And left join will give all the entries of d1. Whereas I need to filter out the common entry and keep the other two of d1. Will boolean masking help? Need the exact syntax in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Did the following steps :

1. outer join between d1 and d2 with Indicator=True
2. extract the left_only entries from the outer join to get the rows_in_df1_not_in_df2.

   ```
                     **2008q2         2009q2          Price Ratio**
   ```

   **State   City**
   Alabama   Montevallo  119000.000000  125200.000000     0.950479
   Alaska    Fairbanks   254733.333333  225833.333333     1.127970

Would like to know if there is any other way like boolean masking?